# Добавить кнопку на WordPress landing

Tags: html, wordpress, html5

Парни, привет. Пытаюсь подключить систему оплаты на landing, для этого необходимо добавить **уникальную** кнопку под каждую карточку товара. Трудность заключается в том, что в index.php всего одна карточка(шаблон), а все остальные товары добавляются через админку сайта, поэтому если я добавляю кнопку в index.php то эта кнопка появляется и у всех остальных товаров (а мне нужна уникальная кнопка для каждого товара).

Landing реализован на голом Wordpress без e-commerce.
Ссылка на [сайт](http://girostyle.com/)!

**P.S:** Полагаю конечный вид страницы index.php со всеми добавленными карточками из админки где-то хранятся в отдельном файле? (Так бы я вручную каждой карточке прописал кнопку с уникальным id и проблема решилась бы).

class общей карточки товара - "catalog"

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/favicon.png"></link>

    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/modal/jquery.arcticmodal-0.3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/style.css">
</head>

<body data-mail="<?php bloginfo('admin_email'); ?>" data-mail-path="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="header-menu">
                <li><a href=".catalog" class="parallax">Каталог</a></li>
                <li><a href=".summergift" class="parallax">Преимущества</a></li>
                <li><a href=".taotao" class="parallax">Приложение TAOTAO</a></li>
                <li><a href=".delivery" class="parallax">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
                <li><a href=".wedo" class="parallax">Доп. услуги</a></li>
                <li><a href=".contacts" class="parallax">Адреса магазинов</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron" style="background: url(<?php the_field('background', 168); ?>) no-repeat top center;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/jumbotron-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
                <a href="#modal-form-call" class="modal-link" data-form="Заказать звонок (в шапке сайта)">заказать звонок</a>
                <!-- <a href="tel:<?php echo get_field('tel', 168); ?>" class="tel"><?php echo get_field('tel', 168); ?></a> -->
<?php 
                    $row = get_field('tels', 168);
                    if ($row) {
                        $count = 0;
                        foreach ($row as $item) {
                            if ($count > 0) {
                                echo '<a class="tel">, </a>';
                            }
                            ?>
                                <a href="tel:<?php echo $item['tel']; ?>" class="tel"><?php echo $item['tel']; ?></a>
                            <?php
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <h1>
                <span>Гироскутеры от производителя</span>
            </h1>
            <h2>
                <span>В честь 8 Марта гироскутер Smart Balance 10B за 13 990 руб.</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a href="#modal-form-choose" class="modal-link modal-link-orange" data-form="Оставить заявку на подбор (1-й экран)">Оставить заявку на подбор</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="catalog">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>
                    <span>Выберите модель гироскутера</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'post_gyroscooter')); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                $title = get_the_title();
                $price_old = get_field('price_old');
                $price_new = get_field('price_new');
                $chars_rows = get_field('characteristics');
                $colors_rows =get_field('colors');
            ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <?php
                            foreach ($colors_rows as $row) {
                                $photo_url = $row['photo']['url'];
                                ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $photo_url; ?>" alt="">
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <h3 class="title offset">
                            <?php echo $title; ?>
                        </h3>
                        <h4 class="subtitle offset">
                            Технические характеристики
                        </h4>
                        <ul class="chars offset">
                            <?php
                                foreach ($chars_rows as $row) {
                                    ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $row['characteristic']; ?></li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                        <h4 class="subtitle offset">
                            Доступные цвета
                        </h4>
                        <ul class="colors offset">
                            <?php
                                foreach ($colors_rows as $row) {
                                    ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $row['color']['url']; ?>" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="../tinkoff-acquiring-popup.php" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','800','600','yes');return false" class="modal-link modal-link-orange">
                            Купить гироскутер
                        </a>
                        <div class="price">

                            <p class="price-old">
                                <?php
                                    if (strlen($price_old) > 2) {
                                        echo $price_old,' руб.';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-new">
                                <span>цена</span> <?php echo $price_new; ?> руб.
                            </p>
                            <div class="kupivkredit-button" id="open" name="open"><div class="kupivkredit-button-content"><i class="kupivkredit-icon"></i>КупиВкредит</div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- post navigation -->
            <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no posts found -->
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>


    <div class="zayavka">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте<br>
                <span>и мы ответим на все ваши вопросы!</span>
            </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" class="hidden" value="Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте (верхняя)">
                <input type="submit" class="hidden">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-submit modal-link-orange" data-form="Оставить заявку на нашем сайте (верхняя, после каталога)">Оставить заявку на сайте</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="summergift">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                Почему <span>гироскутер</span> самый желанный<br>
                подарок этим летом?
            </h2>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>
                    Простота эксплуатации
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Средний вес гироскутера - всего 12-15 кг, а габариты 60х19х18 см., поэтому он легко помещается в багажнике автомобиля, и не занимает много места дома</li>
                    <li>Гироскутер понравится как детям, так и взрослым, ограничения во весу водителя от 20 до 120 кг.</li>
                    <li>Наши гироскутеры оснащены энергоемкими аккумуляторами Samsung. Время полной зарядки всего 2 часа, заряженного аккумулятора хватает на 20-25 км. Цветовой индикатор уровня заряда напомнит о необходимости зарядки</li>
                    <li>В комплект каждого гироскутера входит сумка, для удобногот хранения и транспортировки</li>
                    <li>Скорость движения: 12-20 км./час (в зависимости от модели)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>
                    Интуитивно понятное управление гироскутером
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Управлять гироскутером очень просто, освоить движение смогут и взрослые и дети всего за 5-10 мин.</li>
                    <li>Гироскопические датчики улавливают перемещения центра тяжести тела с независимых платформ и активируют работу двух двигателей расположенных в колесах.</li>
                    <li>Вращение колес осуществляется вперед и назад, соответственно при наклоне тела вперед устройство двигается прямо, при отклонении назад происходит движение в обратном направлении. Для поворота необходимо перенести вес на одну ногу.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>
                    Привлекает<br>внимание
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Гисрокутер - это не просто “последнее слово” с области компактных средств передвижения, гироскутер дарит отличные впечатления водителю и привлекает внимание прохожих</li>
                    <li>Яркий дизайн. Большой выбор моделей и модных принтов, чтобы подчеркнуть индивидуальность</li>
                    <li>Светодиодные фары дополняют дизайн гироскутера, а так же дают дополнительное освещение дорожного полотна в ночное время</li>
                    <li>Каждая модель имеет многофункциональный пульт управления</li>
                    <li>Некторые модели оснащены встроенными колонками Bluetooth 4.0 для воспроизведения музыки, чтобы создавать настроение себе и окружающим</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>
                    Выгодные<br>условия
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Мы осущетсвляем прямые поставки товара из Китая без посредников</li>
                    <li>Предоставляем гарантийное обслуживание в течении 12 месяцев</li>
                    <li>В наших магазинах гироскутеры всегда в наличии</li>
                    <li>Только оригинальные комплектующие</li>
                    <li>Быстрая доставка и качественный сервис</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zayavka">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                Не знаете какой гироскутер выбрать?<br>
                <span>Наш менеджер перезвонит вам и расскажет о каждой модели и поможет с выбором!</span>
            </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" class="hidden" value="Не знаете какой гироскутер выбрать?">
                <input type="submit" class="hidden">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-submit modal-link-orange">Оставить заявку на сайте</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="taotao">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span><?php the_field('header', 285); ?></span></h2>
            <p class="subtitle">
                <?php the_field('subheader', 285); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="right">
                <h3>
                    Дает возможность видеть:
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Заряд батареи  </li>
                    <li>Температуру нагревания двигателей  </li>
                    <li>Скорость движения  </li>
                    <li>Дальность поездки</li>
                    <li>Пробег  </li>
                    <li>Местоположения по GPS</li>
                </ul>
                <h3>
                    С помощью ТАОТАО вы можете регулировать:  
                </h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Скорость движения</li>
                    <li>Чувствительность акселератора</li>
                    <li>Отзывчивость в поворотах</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="works">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span>Как мы работаем</span></h2>
            <p class="text">
                Вы оставляете<br>заявку на сайте
            </p>
            <p class="text">
                Перезванием,<br>оформляем заказ
            </p>
            <p class="text">
                Отправляем заказ<br>курьером или почтой
            </p>
            <p class="text">
                Получаете заказ<br>и оплачиваете
            </p>
            <p class="text">
                Катаетесь и<br>получаете<br>удовольствие
            </p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a href="#modal-form-call" class="modal-link modal-link-orange">Оставить заявку на сайте</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="delivery">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span>Доставка и оплата</span></h2>
            <div class="item">
                <p class="number">
                    1
                </p>
                <div class="text">
                    <p class="description">
                        Выберите удобный<br>
                        способ доставки заказа:
                    </p>
                    <?php
                        $rows = get_field('delivery', 12);
                        if ($rows) {
                            ?>
                                <ul>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                                $method = $row['method'];
                                ?>
                                    <li><?php echo $method; ?></li>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <p class="number">
                    2
                </p>
                <div class="text">
                    <p class="description">
                        Выберите способ<br>
                        оплаты:
                    </p>
                    <?php
                        $rows = get_field('pay', 12);
                        if ($rows) {
                            ?>
                                <ul>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                                $method = $row['method'];
                                ?>
                                    <li><?php echo $method; ?></li>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wedo">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span>А также мы занимаемся</span></h2>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/wedo-1.png" alt="">
                <h3 class="title">
                    Гарантийное обслуживание
                </h3>
                <p class="description">
                    На гироскутеры предоставляется гарантия 12 месяцев. Если у вас возникли проблемы с гироскутером, обязательно позвоните нам.
                </p>
                <a href="#modal-form-zayavka" class="modal-link" data-form="А также мы занимаеимся (Гарантийное обслуживание)">оставить заявку</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/wedo-2.png" alt="">
                <h3 class="title">
                    Запчасти для гироскутеров
                </h3>
                <p class="description">
                    В нашем магазине вы можете приобрести любые запчасти для вашего гироскутера: батареи, корпуса, пульты и др. Для уточнения цен и наличия свяжитесь с менеджером.
                </p>
                <a href="#modal-form-zayavka" class="modal-link" data-form="А также мы занимаеимся (Запчасти для гироскутеров)">оставить заявку</a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/wedo-3.png" alt="">
                <h3 class="title">
                    Негарантийный<br>ремонт
                </h3>
                <p class="description">
                    Если с вашим гироскутером что-то случилось и это не попадает под гарантийный случай, вы можете отдать гироскутер на ремонт в нашу мастерскую.
                </p>
                <a href="#modal-form-zayavka" class="modal-link" data-form="А также мы занимаеимся (Негарантийный ремонт)">оставить заявку</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zayavka">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте<br>
                <span>и мы ответим на все ваши вопросы!</span>
            </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" class="hidden" value="Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте (средняя)">
                <input type="submit" class="hidden">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-submit modal-link-orange">Оставить заявку на сайте</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contacts">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span>Контакты</span></h2>
            <?php
                $rows = get_field('address_and_map', 2);
                if ($rows) {
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        $count++;
                        $address = $row['address'];
                        $img_url = $row['map']['url'];
                        ?>
                            <div class="item">
                                <p class="address">
                                    <?php echo $address; ?>
                                </p>
                                <div class="map">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        if ($count % 2 == 0) {
                            ?>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zayavka footer">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте<br>
                <span>и мы ответим на все ваши вопросы!</span>
            </h2>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" class="hidden" value="Оставьте заявку на нашем сайте (нижняя)">
                <input type="submit" class="hidden">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-submit modal-link-orange">Оставить заявку на сайте</a>
            </form>
            <div class="footer-line">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
                <p class="center">
                    <a href="#modal-form-privacy" class="modal-link">Соглашение об обработке персональных данных</a><br>
                    <a href="#modal-form-kupivkredit" class="modal-link">Условия кредитования системы «КупиВкредит»</a><br>
                    Все права защищены | © ООО "Топ Смарт"
                </p>
                <div class="right">
                    <p>
                        Сайт разработан:
                    </p>
                    <a href="http://filippova-landing.ru/" target="_blank"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-privacy" class="modal-form">
            <h2>Политика конфиденциальности</h2>

            <p>
                Я признаю важность конфиденциальности информации. В этом документе описывается, какую личную информацию я получаю и собираю, когда Вы пользуетесь сайтом filippova-landing.ru. Я надеюсь, что эти сведения помогут Вам принимать осознанные решения в отношении предоставляемой нам личной информации.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Электронная почта</b><br>
            Адрес электронной почты, указываемый Вами при заполнении форм на сайте, не показывается другим посетителям сайта. Я могу сохранять сообщения, полученные по электронной почте и другие письма, оправленные пользователями, чтобы обрабатывать вопросы пользователей, отвечать на запросы и совершенствовать свои службы.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Номер телефона</b><br>
                Номер телефона, указываемый Вами при заполнении форм на сайте, не показывается другим посетителям сайта. Номер телефона используется мной только для связи с Вами.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Цели сбора и обработки персональной информации пользователей</b><br>
            На нашем сайте, посвященном разработке Landing Page, присутствует возможность заполнять формы. Ваше добровольное согласие на получение от нас обратной связи после отправки любой формы на сайте подтверждается путем ввода Вашего имени, E-mail и номера телефона в форму. Имя используется для личного обращения к Вам, E-mail — для отправки Вам писем, номер телефона используется мной только для связи с Вами. Пользователь предоставляет свои данные добровольно, после чего ему высылается письмо с обратной связью или поступает звонок от меня.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Условия обработки и её передачи третьим лицам</b><br>
            Ваше имя, E-mail и номер телефона никогда, ни при каких условиях не будут переданы третьим лицам, исключая случаи, которые связаны с исполнением законодательства.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Протоколирование</b><br>
            При каждом посещении сайта серверы автоматически записывают информацию, которую Ваш браузер передает при посещении веб-страниц. Как правило эта информация включает запрашиваемую веб-страницу, IP-адрес компьютера, тип браузера, языковые настройки браузера, дату и время запроса, а также один или несколько файлов cookie, которые позволяют точно идентифицировать Ваш браузер.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Куки (Cookie)</b><br>
            На сайте filippova-landing.ru используются куки (Cookies), происходит сбор данных о посетителях с помощью сервисов Яндекс.Метрика. Эти данные служат для сбора информации о действиях посетителей на сайте, для улучшения качества его содержания и возможностей. В любое время Вы можете изменить параметры в настройках Вашего браузера таким образом, чтобы браузер перестал сохранять все файлы cookie, а так же оповещал их об отправке. При этом следует учесть, что в этом случае некоторые сервисы и функции могут перестать работать.
            </p>

            <p>
                <b>Изменение Политики конфиденциальности</b><br>
            На этой странице Вы сможете узнать о любых изменениях данной политики конфиденциальности. В особых случаях, Вам будет выслана информация на Ваш E-mail.
            Вы можете задать любые вопросы, написав на E-mail:  info@clientov.net
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-kupivkredit" class="modal-form">
            <h2>Условия кредитования системы «КупиВкредит»:</h2>

            <p>
                <br>
                <img src="html/img/KVK_Logo.png" alt="kupivkredit logo" width="250">
                <br>
                <p>
                    Покупка в кредит - простой, удобный и современный способ покупки товаров в интернет-магазине.<br>
                    Преимущества онлайн-кредитования: <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Для оформления покупки и кредита вам не нужно выходить из дома;</li>
                            <li>В 95% случаев решение по онлайн кредиту принимается за 2 минуты;</li>
                            <li>0% по кредиту до даты первого платежа;</li>
                            <li>Бесплатное досрочное погашение;</li>
                            <li>Бесплатное погашение кредита по всей России (в более чем 160 тысяч партнерских точек приема платежей).</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    Условия кредитования системы «КупиВкредит»: <br>
                    <p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Кредит доступен гражданам России в возрасте от 18 до 70 лет;</li>
                            <li>Сумма кредитования – от 3 000 до 200 000 рублей;</li>
                            <li>Первоначальный взнос - от 0%;</li>
                            <li>Срок кредитования - от 3 до 36 месяцев;</li>
                            <li>% ставка рассчитывается индивидуально.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    Купить товары в кредит очень просто: <br>
                    <p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>При оформлении заказа выберите способ оплаты «Купить в кредит» и подтвердите заказ;</li>
                            <li>Заполните заявку и получите решение ОНЛАЙН в течение 1–2 минут;</li>
                            <li>Подпишите кредитный договор с представителем Банка;</li>
                            <li>Пользуйтесь покупкой и погашайте ежемесячный платеж по кредиту без комиссий.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    По вопросам, связанным с выдачей кредита, обращаться в АО «Тинькофф Банк» на горячую линию: <br>
                    <br>
                    8 (800) 555-08-08 (звонок по России бесплатный и круглосуточный).

                </p>
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-call" class="modal-form">
            <h2>
                Заказать звонок
            </h2>
            <p>
                Оставьте свои данные<br>
                и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время
            </p>
            <form action="#" id="form-modal-zvonok">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" value="Заказать звонок">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-orange">Заказать звонок</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку" class="modal-link-orange">
            </form>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-choose" class="modal-form">
            <h2>
                Заявка на подбор
            </h2>
            <p>
                Оставьте свои данные<br>
                и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время
            </p>
            <form action="#" id="form-modal-zvonok">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" value="Подобрать гироскутер">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-orange">Подобрать гироскутер</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку" class="modal-link-orange">
            </form>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-zayavka" class="modal-form">
            <h2>
                Оставить заявку
            </h2>
            <p>
                Оставьте свои данные<br>
                и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время
            </p>
            <form action="#" id="form-modal-zvonok">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" value="Оставить заявку">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-orange">Оставить заявку</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку" class="modal-link-orange">
            </form>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-buy" class="modal-form">
            <h2>
                Купить гироскутер
            </h2>
            <p>
                Оставьте свои данные<br>
                и мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время
            </p>
            <form action="#" id="form-modal-zvonok">
                <input type="name" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
                <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required pattern="\+{0,1}\d{1,}">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите ваш e-mail">
                <input type="text" name="form" value="Купить гироскутер">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a href="#" class="form-submit-link modal-link-orange">Купить гироскутер</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Оставить заявку" class="modal-link-orange">
            </form>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="modal-form-thanx" class="modal-form">
            <h2>
                Спасибо!
            </h2>
            <p>
                Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время!
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="close">
                закрыть
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/modal/jquery.arcticmodal-0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/main.js"></script>

        var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            s = d.createElement("script"),
            f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

        if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
        } else { f(); }
    })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/42336419" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну и в чем проблема модифицировать этот кусок кода: `<a href="../tinkoff-acquiring-popup.php" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','800','600','yes');return false" class="modal-link modal-link-orange">
                            Купить гироскутер
                        </a>`
Что такого уникального должно быть в кнопке?

Comment: @KAGGDesign вы немного не про ту кнопку, с этой всё впорядке :-) 
Речь идет про: `<div class="kupivkredit-button" id="open" name="open"><div class="kupivkredit-button-content"><i class="kupivkredit-icon"></i>КупиВкредит</div></div>`
За данной кнопкой стоит блок php, который нельзя модифицировать (он от самого Тинькоффа), поэтому необходимо под каждый товар сделать уникальную кнопку с нужной ценой товара.

Comment: Как догадаться из вашего вопроса, о какой кнопке вы спрашиваете? Какой такой блок "от самого", в чем должна быть уникальность кнопки?  Ничего не понятно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ограничение в 3 тысячи символов не дали мне написать вопрос еще подробнее :-( На самом деле тут нет разницы о какой кнопке я спрашиваю, так как суть не в кнопке ("кнопку" можно заменить хоть на div-блок, хоть на заголовок).

Вопрос стоит: как можно отредактировать кодом карточки товара, которые создаются через админку?

Ну а если, все-таки, хотите углубиться в суть, то: у "Тинькова" есть система КупиВкредит, и на моем сайте она интегрирована через php - подробнее [тут](https://form.kupivkredit.ru/developers/example),

Comment: @KAGGDesign ,Модифицировать их код невозможно, сумма товара прописывается в данный php блок и выводится на кнопку, которая запускает этот php. Поэтому, для каждого товара нужен отдельный php блок с уникальной кнопкой. Да говно-код, криво, Don't Repeat Yourself, вся фигня... Но по другому тут не видится вариантов.

Comment: @KAGGDesign если вы на [сайте](http://www.girostyle.com/) нажмете кнопку "КупиВкредит" под первой карточкой с товаром, то увидите форму заполнения. Таких кнопок надо под каждый товар, с разной ценой кредита итд... К тому же из-за того, что кнопка шаблонная и автоматически копируется под все товары, происходит конфликт id и кроме первой кнопки другие не работают.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос несколько размыт, понятие уникальности (которую можно реализовать по-разному и разными способами) не определено.
Вот самое простое решение.

1. Во-первых, сайт - не на голом Wordpress. В коде видно, что используется плагин Advanced Custom Fields.
2. Это открывает перед нами чудесные возможности, позволяя сделать следующее:

а) Создать новое текстовое поле (предположим, с ярлыком my-unique-id в существующей или новой группе полей.

б) Ввести нужные вам значения этого поля во все соответствующие записи.

в) Вывести значение поля в нужном месте, примерно так (как это делается в данном шаблоне, например, для поля телефонных номеров)

```
<div class="kupivkredit-button" id="<?php echo get_field ('my-unique-id')?>" name="open"><div class="kupivkredit-button-content"><i class="kupivkredit-icon"></i>КупиВкредит</div></div>
```

Comment: Вроде, улавливаю ход мыслей, но не понимаю итога. 

_б) Ввести нужные вам значения этого поля во все соответствующие записи._

Вы же поняли, что мне нужен доступ к карточкам товара по отдельности? Для каждой карточки товара будет свой отдельный php-блок, с нужной ценой, который будет выполняться посредством нажатия кнопки "КупиВкредит"

Comment: Об этом и речь.
В каждой карточке вручную введите значение вновь созданного поля для уникального id.
Плагин полей есть в админ-меню?  Надпись типа "Произвольные поля" или Advanced Custom Fields? Что-то должно быть, телефоны же туда забиты.

Comment: Да, вот сейчас в голове сложился пазл! За исключением того, как к этим кнопкам потом привязать нужный мне [php-блок](https://form.kupivkredit.ru/developers/example). Как я понимаю значения созданных вручную полей на выходе получаются string и через php их не зацепить? `button = document.getElementById("open");` вот тут оно цепляется через id, как в нашем случае быть?

Comment: А какие данные требуется передавать на внешнюю страницу? Там много параметров.

Comment: Много да... Они, почти, все и нужны. 6-7 точно надо (там есть цена, кол-во, наименование товара + еще есть рабочие данные терминала). По хорошему бы как-то присвоить кнопке свой id и тогда всё заработает.

Comment: В этом случае надо пример php кода использовать в шаблоне Вордпресс и передавать туда значения переменных.
Кнопка тут вообще ни при чем, она просто запускает скрипт.

Comment: Ну php пример уже внедрен в шаблон wordpress и успешно работает, только как вы уже поняли нужны разные данные передать в шаблон для разных товаров.
Можно через поля насоздавать кнопок, как вы изначально говорили, а дальше надо как то заставить их передавать разные данные в сам php-код, хотя бы параметры 'сумма' 'название' передавались, а всё остальное там идентично.

Comment: Если вы разберетесь, где на вашем сайте вводятся, например, цены и где в шаблоне они потом выводятся (и как) - все остальное будет просто.
Я не вижу, как внедрен php пример в вашем шаблоне.

Comment: Так а че тут разбираться :D `$price_new = get_field('price_new');`

Comment: А пример php этот внедрен копи-пастом, ибо там ничего менять не надо особо. Изменил только массив (удалил лишнее) и подставил свои "ключи" от личного кабинета в системе оплаты...

Comment: Оставите messager какой-нибудь? Я бы, возможно, по-приставал с вопросами еще немного, а тот тут не особо удобно?! Вечерком домой приду - попробую реализовать то, что мы тут понапечатали :-)

Comment: skype: eldinorr

Comment: Супер! Заявку, чтобы быть лучшими друзьями кинул, отпишусь потом о результатах :o

Answer (score 0):

Использовать атрибут data и вписывать туда данные из произвольных полей, например.

[HTML data-* Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Comment: Вопрос не в том как унифицировать кнопку, а как ее вставить в нужную мне карточку товара.

Answer (score 0):

Можно в id кнопки, указывать ID записи, это если я правильно понял, что надо сделать

```html
<a href="../tinkoff-acquiring-popup.php" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" onclick="centeredPopup(this.href,'myWindow','800','600','yes');return false" class="modal-link modal-link-orange">
                            Купить гироскутер
                        </a>
```